# NSSavePanel accessory view disabled in macOS 11 Big Sur

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nssavepanel, macos-big-sur

- I create a new macOS app in XCode.
- I add the entitlement `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` with value `YES` (to allow usage of `NSSavePanel`)
- In `AppDelegate.m`, I implement `applicationDidFinishLaunching` as follows:

  ```
  - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSSavePanel* nssavepanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    NSButton* nsbutton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 50, 20)];
    [nsbutton setTitle:@"Button title"];
    [nssavepanel setAccessoryView:[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 80)]];
    [[nssavepanel accessoryView] addSubview:nsbutton];
    [nssavepanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSModalResponse result) {}];
  }
  ```

When I start the application, I see a panel with a button.

On **macOS 10.15.3**, I can click the button in the acceessory view.

On **macOS 11.0 Beta (20A4300b)**, I **cannot** click the button -- the whole accessory view seems to be disabled. (If I use `runModal` or `beginSheetModalForWindow` instead of `beginWithCompletionHandler`, the accessory view works as expected.) Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Just FYI - it's fixed in the 20A5323l

Comment: @zrzka I just tried with 20A5323l, and the error persists. Did you try it as well/do you have a credible source that Apple fixed it and it should work?

Comment: I tested it on < beta 3 (doesn't work) and on beta 3 = 20A5323l (does work). Your code copy & pasted + added target/action (works without it as well) - check [the screenshot](https://cln.sh/3UO9Zj).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, and it looks the same on my machine, but I *cannot click* the button. If I set focus to the "tags" combobox, the button/accessory view seems to be unlocked, but before that, it does not respond to my clicks.

Comment: The error persists in macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 Beta (20B5022a).